# How to use Scanners on users input

Tags: java, printing

I am trying to create a scanner that executes depending on the users input, but it isn't working.  This is a sample:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Type in:");
    System.out.println("Love");
    System.out.println("Hate");
    System.out.println("What ?"); 

    Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);  
    String n = c.nextLine();

    System.out.println("You Type in " + n);

    if(n == Love) {
       System.out.print("Jesus Loves You");
    } 
 }
}
```

What do you think might be the problem?

Comment: `var name = document.getElementById("name").value; alert(name);`

Comment: Should work: http://jsfiddle.net/YL52j/. Something you not telling us?

Comment: It keeps giving undefined

Comment: Is this your actual HTML and JavaScript (copied 1 on 1)?

Comment: Ok the truth is that I am using objects() to do this and this is my code : operator.name = document.getElementById("name").value; . Thats what am using

Comment: We would need the actual code in order to replicate your problem, if you can update your question

Comment: Ok the code goes like this :var operator = new Object();

 operator.name = document.forms.myform.name.value;      function nameIt() {
    
    alert(operator.name);
    }

Comment: The code has been given

Comment: I think this is the first time I've seen someone edit their question to completely replace their question with a new, totally unrelated one.. especially after answers have been given.  Don't do that, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the variable.

```
function nameIt() {
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
alert(name);
}
```

Comment: Check for typos, open your developer tools (F12) and toggle to console. What does it say?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you meant to save the value of the input into a variable `name`.

```
function nameIt() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    alert(name);
}
```

Comment: Am telling you it dosent still work it still give's undefined